# How to model certain effect appearing in the residuals with GLM poisson family?

Tags: generalized-linear-model, residuals, poisson-regression

It is a long description, so please have some patience.

I am fitting a GLM (Poisson Family) to a daily timeseries from 2012 to 2017. The objective is to predict 2018. I have created model1 including the following variables as factors:

- 'Day' (Day of Month)
- 'DayOfWeek'
- 'Month'
- 'Holiday'

And the variable 'Year' as continuous. The response variable is called 'Units'.

I am using GlmnetUtils (Interface to Glmnet that allow the use of formulas) in R as follows:

```r
    model1 <- glmnet(Units ~ Day + Month + DayOfWeek + Year + Holiday,
                     data = df,
                     standardize = TRUE,
                     alpha = 1,
                     use.model.frame = TRUE,
                     family = "poisson")
```

model1 achieves an $R^2$ of 0.8575

And this is the Residual vs Fitted Plot of model1

[image: Residuals vs Fitted Model 1]

I have identified the points with large residuals as peaks happening in the last working day of the month. I have created a variable called LastWorkingDayInMonth (LWDiM) and fitted a model2

```r
    model2 <- glmnet(Units ~ Day + Month + DayOfWeek + Year + Holiday + 
                             LastWorkingDayInMonth ,
                     data = df,
                     standardize = TRUE,
                     alpha = 1,
                     use.model.frame = TRUE,
                     family = "poisson")
```

model2 achieves an $R^2$ of 0.8719 which is some improvement over model1 but not so much.

Nevertheless, the points corresponding to LastWrokingDayInMonth still have large residuals. Here there is an image of the residuals with discrimination between points that are not in the LastWorkingDayInMonth and those that are. The last ones also colored by year

[image: Residuals vs Fitted model2]

So you can see that there is clearly a relationship between 'Residuals' and the variable 'Year' where residuals from earlier years are smaller and residuals in later years are larger.

So here is model3 with the interaction LastWorkingDayInMonth*Year trying to capture that effect:

```r
    model3 <- glmnet(Units ~ Day + Month + DayOfWeek + Year + Holiday + LastWorkingDayInMonth + LastWorkingDayInMonth*Year ,
                     data = df,
                     standardize = TRUE,
                     alpha = 1,
                     use.model.frame = TRUE,
                     family = "poisson")
```

model3 achieves an $R^2$ 0.8719 which is not improvement over model2.

Moreover, here there is an image of the residuals of the points with LastWorkingDayInMonth = 1 vs Year.

[image: Residuals vs Year for LWDiM]

So this clearly gives me evidence that those residuals for which LastWorkingDayInMonth = 1 should be able to be modeled approximately linear by the interaction LastWorkingDayInMonth*Year as seen in model3.

In fact, if I train an extraModel in the above data I get

```r
    extraModel -> lm(Residuals ~ Year, data = FilteredByLastWorkingDayInMonth)
    summary(extraModel)
    Call:
    lm(formula = Residuals ~ Year, data = FilteredByLastWorkingDayInMonth)
    
    Residuals:
       Min     1Q Median     3Q    Max 
    -699.2 -248.8  -26.0  206.0  841.4 
    
    Coefficients:
                  Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
    (Intercept) -543906.82   45951.75  -11.84   <2e-16 ***
    Year            270.00      22.81   11.84   <2e-16 ***
    ---
    Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
    
    Residual standard error: 330.6 on 70 degrees of freedom
    Multiple R-squared:  0.6668,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.6621 
    F-statistic: 140.1 on 1 and 70 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

Which shows that Year is significant in predicting those residuals.

All above suggests that I should:

1. Run model2 for predicting 'Units', then
2. Check if it is a LastWorkingDayInMonth. If so, then
3. Run extraModel and add this to the prediction of Step 1.

In fact, this two step-model achieves a $R^2$ of 0.8950 and now the residuals plot looks much better

[image: Residuals vs Fitted model3]

But this makes no sense to me. Applying extraModel to only points with LastWorkingDayInMonth = 1 should be the same as the interaction added to model3 that did not reduce the $R^2$. It is like a contradiction. I have checked the code to make sure I am not making mistakes but I cannot find anything out of the ordinary.

So my hypothesis right now are:

1. This is in fact a contradiction and there must be a coding mistake.
2. There could be some statistical considerations that I am not aware in the sense that poisson Glm is fitting the points in a transformed space ( Linear in Log(Units) ) and the problem I am having actually makes sense.

**Remarks**: I am using Glmnet just because it has the option to "standarize" the data before fitting the model and because later I am going to optimize the model with ridge-lasso. Anyway, I have checked with Glm and I have the same results.

Comment: Keep in mind that mean = variance in Poisson distribution.

Comment: @a_statistician So the fact that mean and variance are equal in the Poisson Distribution implies that the increase in variability in those peak values are not penalized in finding the coefficients so the coefficients are unchanged?

Comment: Yes. I did not find any abnormality in your first residual graph visually. I cannot go farther because i have no date.